# Connecting to VPNs and my ISP

Tags: vpn, openvpn, isp

So pretty basic question,

Say I connect to a VPN server using OpenVPN or Wireguard or whatever. For example, I connect to a VPN server with the IP address 55.66.77.88, using OpenVPN. Can the ISP I'm using to connect to this server transparently see that I'm connecting to 55.66.77.88 and the port I'm connecting on, or does OpenVPN find a way to obscure this in some way?

i.e. Basically, can my ISP easily see what VPN service I'm using?

Thanks.

Comment: It's possible to obscure, but not with a publicly available VPN service. If you are using a private VPN service it depends on why the ISP shoudn't know that you are using VPN?!

Answer (score 1):

At most your ISP can see that you are using a VPN service.

In order to use the internet your computer must send packets to computer addresses. Without a VPN packets will leave your network and go to all the various machines on the internet.

With a VPN those packets are captured, encrypted and then enclosed in another packet. That packet *must* go somewhere to be decrypted and forwarded on to their real destination.  In order for that packet to go anywhere you have to address it to someone, that someone being your VPN provider.

So yes. Your ISP can see that you are connecting to an IP address, and the briefest of searches will tell them that the IP is that of a VPN provider.  They may already know the key VPN IP addresses.

What they won't know is where the data is destined for *after* the VPN.

The VPN provider themselves will be able to tell where your packets are going though, so you are mainly moving your trust away from your ISP to a VPN provider that may or may not have different jurisdictions or affiliations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was starting to figure is much.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer - yes. Your ISP can see your external IP, the port you are connecting from, and the IP and port of the VPN server.  In the typical cade this is enough to indicate the VPN protocol and port.

There are ways to somewhat obscure this using something called domain fronting  - Your VPN provider could use an alternative port and protocol (for example run a VPN across https) to a server which is on a CDN.  This is not very common anymore - as CDN providers are loathe to offer this service.  - See https://nordvpn.com/blog/domain-fronting/ (and it requires an interface that's not ideal for VPN)